# OP amp, Attempt Out > Rail

Tags: operational-amplifier

If you try to obtain a voltage greater than the power rails of an op-amp, what will happen?

I am assuming that the output == the rail limiting it. Is that correct, or does it break the op-amp?

Comment: That depends on the op-amp. But most will not break, some will reach (nearly) the supply, many will not even reach the supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

Most opamps will have an output arrangement similar to the push-pull arrangement of the old 741. Others will have FET transistors rather than BJTs. In either case if the top transistor (red oval) is turned on the output will be pulled to positive rail. If the bottom transistor (green oval) is turned on the output will be pulled to negative rail. How close they get depends on the exact output configuration and the driving circuitry.

> If you try to obtain a voltage greater than the power rails of an op-amp, what will happen?

The output will turn on as much as it can and will limit your output somewhere between the rails.

> I am assuming that the output == the rail limiting it. Is that correct, or does it break the op-amp?

You are correct in that the output will be limited. It will only "break" it in that if it latches up there may be a short delay for it to unlatch and begin normal operation again.

Note that this does not take into account what happens if the output is driven outside the rails by an external circuit feeding *back* into the output.

Comment: Holy cow, thank you! You explained it really well for me.

Answer (score 2):

At the very best, in a a RR Output (RR = Rail to Rail) op-amp, the circuit will have been designed to run up to and very close to the rails of the op-amp.  Usually however, this is not the case and the outputs will not come close, these values are specified in the data-sheet.

For an op-amp to exceed the the rails would mean that it would have to have some onboard voltage boosting circuit.  While possible, I am unaware of such a beast.

Is running to the rail or even to the maximum of the rail damaging?

No, but it's not usually good design (but sometimes is) as the op-amp could loose control over it's feedback loop and enter into a different regime of operation.  If you do this, it should be done deliberately and with knowledge.

Comment: Exiting the feedback loop can cause output stage saturation. The behavior of op-amps are usually specified for the behavior when leaving saturation.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using an inverting amp to bring a voltage within a 0-5V to range, and another with rails at -5&5 to make sure it says within range, and bring it back to polarity.  As long as it doesn't break, I think I'm good.