# Help explain op-amp description by Forrest Mims

Tags: operational-amplifier, basic

The following description is from the book [Op-Amp IC Circuits by Forrest Mims (2nd edition 1994)](https://archive.org/details/Forrest_Mims-Engineers_Mini-Notebook_Op_Amp_Ic_Circuits_Radio_Shack_Electronics):

[image]

As a newbie, the entire paragraph is counter-intuitive to me.  If *amplitude* is reduced, why is there a reference to a *gain*?

Also, if there exists a better textbook on the subject, I would appreciate that information as well.

Comment: there's literally thousands of basic electronics textbooks out there – not all fit everyone, but it's safe to say that you'll find better resources than a handwritten '85 script e.g. on TI's website.

Comment: other than that, think of this: the opamp theoretically would amplify by a factor of say 1 million. With the appropriate feedback, only by a factor of 2. That's a reduction by 500,000, but still positive gain.

Comment: Negative Feedback might seem counter-intuitive , but it uses the output /Input ratio to null the differential input error.=0  Thus it inverts signals, and inverts impedance of feedback reactance as well

Comment: There may be better Op-amp books, but IMO the best overall analog electronics book is *The Art of Electronics* by Paul Horowitz and Winfield Hill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is reference to gain because an opamp is designed to, in the absence of negative feedback, amplify the signal very very large, but vaguely specified amount. This is the so-called "open loop" gain. Open-loop because there is no negative feedback so no loop is closed by a signal going from the output back to the input.

Negative feedback reigns in this very large, vaguely specified output so it is no longer as large as it would have been, but is still at a level larger than the input, and it is now well specified. This is the so-called "closed loop" gain.

We do this because it is difficult to manufacture transistors with accurate and stable gains, but it is easy to manufacture transistors with very very large gains. Then you can use resistor ratios which are easy to manufacture accurately to get the exact gain you want.

The reason a very large, poorly specified gain becomes a smaller, well-specified gain when you add negative feedback is due to the math. The equation for the closed-loop gain (which implies negative feedback) contains resistor values and the open-loop gain as variables. But as the open-loop gain approaches infinite, it approximates itself out of the equation and disappears leaving only resistor values behind.

Comment: Where does an op-amp get the resources to amplify the signal?  (I.e. in terms of  the law of conservation of energy.)

Comment: @Sabuncu That's why op-amps have power supply pins.

Comment: @Sabuncu:  The opamp gets the additional energy from the powersupply.

Comment: @Sabuncu Contrast that with a transformer that might amplify the voltage or current but does so by reducing the current or voltage, respectively. No power pins, so power in = power out.

Comment: DKNguyen, thank you.  @JRE thank you, your GitHub site is simply great.

Comment: @Sabuncu, see if [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239731/op-amp-attempt-out-rail) and my answer helps your understanding.

Comment: @Transistor I appreciate your help but your answer is way over my head at this early stage. :) I hope to understand it one day.  E.g. the image referenced there talks about "current mirrors", which mean nothing to me.  But thanks just the same.

Comment: @Sabuncu: No problem. My technique is learn the new words and how to pronounce them. Then get familiar with the context they're used in. Read, read, read and understanding follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you decrease amplification from 10x to 9x, there is still amplification or gain as amplification is larger than 1x.

Answer (score 1):

check out the useful formula Vout = Vin * G/(1 + G*H)

where G is the forward gain (magnitude)/angle such as 50,000x at 89 degrees.

And H is the feedback ratio.

If in inverting topology, with Rin = 1KOhm and Rfeedback= 10K ohm (thus the expected gain is MINUS 10.00) use the H = 0.1000